# OR function not returning "TRUE" when parameters met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large data set and have created a number of rules I want to use to filter out some of the unnecessary data points.

Here is a simplified example of some data:

```
    A         B        C        D
1 PIPPIP      0    0.411298  PIPPIP
2 PIPPIP     0.6    0.40924  PIPPIP
3 PIPPIP      1    0.378689  PIPPIP
4 PIPPIP      1    0.75456   PIPPIP
5 PIPPIP     0.8   0.967534  PIPPIP
6 PIPPYG     0.9   0.865426  PIPPYG
7 PIPPYG     0.9   0.789654  PIPPYG
```

An example rule would be to separate all data points which have both B > 0.89 and C value of > 0.749 if D=PIPPIP or >0.849 if D=PIPPYG

To do this I am using the formula:

```
=AND(B1>0.89,(OR((AND(D1="PIPPIP",C1>0.749)),(AND(D1="PIPPYG",C1>0.849)))))
```

However, this always returns a FALSE value even for points which meet both criteria. I know that there must be an error in the formula but I can't figure out what the error is. Would someone please point it out to me?

Or is the problem that I can't nest OR functions like I have?

I would really appreciate if someone would walk me through this.

Thanks.

Comment: `=AND(B1>0.89,(OR(AND(D1="PIPPIP",C1>0.749),AND(D1="PIPPYG",C1>0.849)))) ` ?  It may be because you're closing out the `Or` early with the extra parenthesis)?

Comment: `B > 0.89 and C value of > 0.749 if D=PIPPIP or >0.849 if D=PIPPYG` - so Having trouble understanding that - _separate all data points_ (what are data points in this context?).  So if `B1 > 0.89 and C1 > 0.749` then check if `D1 = PIPPIP or D1>0.849, but only if D1=PIPPYG`?  Trying to understand what you mean but you've got that  '>0.849` sounding like it's attached to column D, but only column B and C have numbers in.

Comment: `B > 0.89 and C value of > 0.749 if D=PIPPIP or >0.849 if D=PIPPYG` Maybe it's `(IF D=PIPPIP AND B1> 0.89 AND C1 > 0.749) OR (IF D1=PIPPYG AND C1>0.849) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the best you can do is the following:

- Select the cell with the formula.
- Evaluate the formula step by step with the built-in evaluator in Excel (Tab Formulas>Evaluate Formula> Evaluate):

[image]

- Find your error and fix it.

Comment: That is the exact tool I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @dev1998 - congrats for widening the boundaries of Excel. If you try the evaluator on array formulas you would be amazed :)

Comment: @dev1998 Just don't use it on `SUMPRODUCT` on thousands of rows.  You'll be horrified. :)  Maybe _one day_ they'll allow you to change the size of the dialog box as well......

Answer (score 1):

I tried your exact example and there are 2 rows that returns true. I did check the formula and it seems fine as well:
[image]

if it's not the result you are expecting, maybe you could add a column and tell us which one are suppose to return true/false.

Comment: fwiw, I concur; there is nothing wrong with the op's formula beyond an over exuberance of brackets. `=AND(B1>0.89, OR(AND(D1="PIPPIP",C1>0.749), AND(D1="PIPPYG",C1>0.849)))`

Comment: Yep, after ignoring the sample rule which makes no sense to me and looking at the formula I came up with exact same formula as @Jeeped.