# Excel Conditional Formatting Nest AND and OR

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a rather quick hopefully not too complicated question for you guys. I'm trying to use conditional formatting where I want a cell to turn red if the following statements are False or If the conditions are not met.

I'm using the Formula for Conditional formatting where you have to input it manually. The real problem I'm having is using a nested AND and OR.

Here's the formula I have for conditional formatting (one thing to note that, maybe I could be wrong, but my 2013 Excel is treating OR as an AND and vice versa. I've tested it many times and this is the case, so the formula you see below treats OR and AND as I mentioned. In short, pretend that AND is OR and OR is AND. But if it confuses you, just go with the correct convention:

```
=AND(OR(SUM(A1:A5)=0,SUM(B2:B5)=0),OR(SUM(C1:C5)=0,SUM(D1:D5)=0),SUM(E1:E5)=0)
```

So basically, say I have cell 'A7'. I want 'A7' to be red until there's a number in

1. Both A1:A5 and B2:B5  or:
2. E1:E5   or;
3. Both C1:C5 and D1:D5   -----> here's where it doesn't work.

Points 1 and 2 above work as desired, but when I add the second 'OR' it doesn't work. Remember, for some reason my Excel COnditional Formatting treats OR like and AND and vice versa so when I say:

```
OR(SUM(A1:A5)=0,SUM(B1:B5)=0)
```

It treats it like an AND where both conditions must be true, therefore, I've been following this convention.

So basically how do I have more that one OR statements within AND as shown above.

I hope I made the question clear. Appreciate your guys help!! If you can also tell me a general rule on how nested And OR works, that would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Check out "Evaluate Formula". [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171896/or-function-not-returning-true-when-parameters-met/48171947#comment83323629_48171947]

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't show me any formula because my cell itself doesn't have a formula. I think it's because it's conditional formatting. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: You say "I want 'A7' to be red until......" ....Does that mean that A7 is already red and you want the conditional formatting to change it based on your conditions.....or do you want to make it red because of the conditions?

Comment: 1. Yes, A7 is remains red until of one the conditions is. Meaning, the 'Red' Cell goes away once the conditions are met. 2. Yes, any of the cells within within A1:A5 (not all of them).

Answer (score 1):

Select A7, fill it with red colour (standard fill), clear any existing CF from it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(COUNT(E1:E5),AND(COUNT(A1:A5),COUNT(B2:B5)),AND(COUNT(C1:C5),COUNT(D1:D5)))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select No Colour fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `=IF(OR(AND((SUM(A1:A5)>0),(SUM(B2:B5)>0)),SUM(E1:E5)>0,AND((SUM(C1:C5)>0),(SUM(D2:D5)>0)))=FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)`

I put this into a cell first and used the Evaluate Formula before pasting it into the Conditional rule.

Set the text to be red if this is true.

Comment: @pnuts OP implied positive numbers by using = 0 as a condition in the example formula. Your answer is good because the OP also mentions that a number has to be present and 0 is a number. Maybe today we'll find out whether 0 counts or not.